# How to receive a video stream from source in my android app

Tags: android

I have a source that transmits video in H264 format (in this case it is Colasoft Packet Player which transmits video stream through IP:PORT) and I want to be able to listen and receive the video stream in my Android app.
I read a lot of things across the internet about Socket, DatagramSocket and AudioManager, but I'm totally confused about what exactly I need and how to implement that.

What I need is to be able to capture the video frame by frame.
I would love to get some help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [VLC Android library](https://github.com/videolan/vlc-android)

And [here](https://imstudio.medium.com/android-how-to-embed-vlc-media-player-to-android-app-1828d34c54f) there's an explanation on how to embed it into your app.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, I have added an update to my question - ```What I need is to be able to capture the video frame by frame```. Is it possible with  VLC Android library?

Comment: You need to explore the VLC Android library in order to do that, honestly I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can let ffmpeg do this job.

Have a look at:

https://github.com/alphons/SegmentationStreaming